# Redirect specific file request (at any location) to specific location

Tags: file, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, request

I have a specific file, let's call it 'myfile.abc', that I need to have redirected to a specific location, no matter what location it's requested from. For instance:

```
/folder1/myfile.abc
/folder2/myfile.abc
/folder3/myfile.abc
```

I need all the above to be redirected to (as an example):

```
/myfolder/myfile.abc
```

How do I achieve that within the .htaccess file?

In response to Gumbo's answer, I now have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !=myfolder
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/myfile.abc$ myfolder/myfile.abc [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !=myfolder
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/myfile\.abc$ myfolder/myfile.abc [L]
```

And if you want an external redirect, add the *R* flag with an optional redirect status code (`[L,R]`/`[L,R=301]`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it works great on a page that requests this file, but I get 500 error on other pages. It's on a WordPress site, so the .htaccess contains the WP redirect code too - I've added what I have in the .htaccess file to the main question. Could you please advise on what the issue is, thanks.

Comment: No matter, I've gotten it working by shuffling the rules around a bit.